# Distance from W(West) to vernal equinox

Tags: right-ascension

I am pretty new to astronomy and the project I am currently working on requires some knowledge of equatorial coordinate system.
As long as I have been researching this question, I understood that vernal equinox is the origin of this system. At this moment I am stuck with task of finding distance on celestial sphere between west(on horizon) and vernal equinox.
So, how do you count this distance?

Comment: The position of the vernal equinox varies depending on where you are and what time it is.

Comment: I realize that and was hoping if there is any formula determining its distance depending on latitude and longitude.

Comment: Are you looking for the elevation and azimuth of the vernal equinox at a given time and place? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/14508/21 has equations for that

Comment: Do you mean the vernal equinox or the First Point of Aries - ie the point at which the celestial equator and the ecliptic meet?

Comment: Oh, actually I am looking for a way of finding star's position(with given right ascension and declination) on sky for given latitude and longitude at a given time

Comment: I do actually mean this point.

Answer (score 1):

The right ascension of the point on the horizon and due west is LST - 6 hours, where LST is the Local Sidereal Time. The LST can be calculated from knowing the date, time, and longitude. The declination of the west point is 0 degrees. So the angle between that right ascension and 0 hours right ascension (the vernal equinox) is just the difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to develop the answer from first principles, then I suggest you use formulas already published.  One source is "Astronomical Algorithms", by Jean Meeus.  http://www.willbell.com/math/mc1.htm

I don't have a copy of this boo, so I can't guarantee that it contains what you want.

I have no connection with the author or the publisher.